# Optimizing multiple pandas resample operations

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, resampling

I have this dataset that consists of *type of action, x, y, and z coordinates, label, and timestamps*. What I want to do is to calculate some variables based on the coordinates and thus get more features.
Let's say that I have around 50k entries and some of the measurements are up to 20 measurements per second. I want to resample them for every 1, 3 and 5 seconds. The following script is working but is extremely inefficient and it usually runs for several hours. It does the job, but I'm sure it can be better. I'm not entirely familiar with python and pandas optimization options and I'm currently looking them up. I've tried to use `df.resample(....).last()` (in an attempt to do the resampling once) and it is kind of strange that it produced 2995753 rows, which is far more than 50k....
Do you have any suggestions how to optimize the following script?

```
type = 16
bin = '5S'

type_str = 'accelerometer' if type == 2 else 'gyroscope'
name = str(type) + "_" + str(type_str)

# data load and basic preparation
csv = pd.read_csv('data/cleaned_' + str(type) + '.csv', sep=',')
df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
df.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['label'] = df['label'].astype('int')
# df['time'] = df['date'].dt.time

resampled = pd.DataFrame({})  # empty df for the new features

resampled['label'] = df.resample(bin, on="date")['label'].mean()  # get the avg value for the target action / the label

resampled['n'] = df.resample(bin, on="date")['label'].count()

resampled['x'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").x.mean()
resampled['y'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").y.mean()
resampled['z'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").z.mean()

# get the max value for each dimension for every group - https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-group-data-by-different-time-intervals-using-python-pandas-eb7134f9b9b0
resampled['x_avg_max'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").x.max()
resampled['x_avg_min'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").x.min()
resampled['x_range'] = resampled['x_avg_max'] - resampled['x_avg_min']
resampled['x_standard_deviation'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").x.std()
resampled['x_variance'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").x.var()
resampled['x_skew'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").x.agg(skew)
resampled['x_kurtosis'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").x.agg(kurtosis)

resampled['y_avg_max'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").y.max()
resampled['y_avg_min'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").y.min()
resampled['y_range'] = resampled['y_avg_max'] - resampled['y_avg_min']
resampled['y_standard_deviation'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").y.std()
resampled['y_variance'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").y.var()
resampled['y_skew'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").y.agg(skew)
resampled['y_kurtosis'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").y.agg(kurtosis)

resampled['z_avg_max'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").z.max()
resampled['z_avg_min'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").z.min()
resampled['z_range'] = resampled['z_avg_max'] - resampled['z_avg_min']
resampled['z_standard_deviation'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").z.std()
resampled['z_variance'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").z.var()
resampled['z_skew'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").z.agg(skew)
resampled['z_kurtosis'] = df.resample(bin, on="date").z.agg(kurtosis)

resampled.fillna(0, inplace=True)  # replace empty values with zeros
# new features
resampled['svm'] = np.sqrt(resampled['x'] * resampled['x'] + resampled['y'] * resampled['y'] + resampled['z'] * resampled['z'])
resampled['vmm'] = resampled[["x", "y", "x"]].max(axis=1)  # get the max value for each time group, regardless if it is x, y, or z
resampled['sma'] = abs(resampled['x']) + abs(resampled['y']) + abs(resampled['z'])
resampled['ai'] = resampled['svm'] / resampled['n']

# remove rows if n=0 -> no measurements from the sensors
resampled = resampled.drop(resampled[resampled.n == 0].index)

print(resampled)
resampled.to_csv("data/resampled/resampled_" + str(type) + "_" + str(bin) + ".csv")
```

Comment: Please provide the area where it uses the most time. You could at some time measurement into it, that it is clear, when it takes the most time. With that bride question the question will be closed.

Comment: @PV8 so far it looks like the skew and kurtosis operations are the ones that are slowing down the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def skew(x):
    return pd.Series(x).skew()

def kurtosis(x):
    return pd.Series(x).kurtosis()

type = 16
bin = '5S'

type_str = 'accelerometer' if type == 2 else 'gyroscope'
name = str(type) + "_" + str(type_str)

# data load and basic preparation
csv = pd.read_csv('data/cleaned_' + str(type) + '.csv', sep=',')
df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['label'] = df['label'].astype('int')

# Resample data and calculate statistics and features
resampled = df.resample(bin, on='date').agg({
    'label': 'mean',
    'x': ['mean', 'max', 'min', 'std', 'var', skew, kurtosis],
    'y': ['mean', 'max', 'min', 'std', 'var', skew, kurtosis],
    'z': ['mean', 'max', 'min', 'std', 'var', skew, kurtosis]
})

resampled.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in resampled.columns.values]

# Calculate additional features
resampled['n'] = df.resample(bin, on='date')['label'].count()
resampled['x_range'] = resampled['x_max'] - resampled['x_min']
resampled['y_range'] = resampled['y_max'] - resampled['y_min']
resampled['z_range'] = resampled['z_max'] - resampled['z_min']
resampled['svm'] = np.sqrt(resampled['x_mean']**2 + resampled['y_mean']**2 + resampled['z_mean']**2)
resampled['vmm'] = resampled[['x_mean', 'y_mean', 'z_mean']].max(axis=1)
resampled['sma'] = abs(resampled['x_mean']) + abs(resampled['y_mean']) + abs(resampled['z_mean'])
resampled['ai'] = resampled['svm'] / resampled['n']

# Remove rows where n=0 -> no measurements from the sensors
resampled = resampled[resampled['n'] != 0]

print(resampled)
resampled.to_csv("data/resampled/resampled_" + str(type) + "_" + str(bin) + ".csv")
```

Try this, then measure the different areas where it cost more time and try to improve it or give feedback.

Comment: ok, it looks like the skew and kurtosis are the two most time-consuming operations. I wasn't aware of the possibility of doing multiple resample operations at once, thanks for pointing that out. I was wondering if I try to use something like modin will it be efficient and applicable in my case.

Comment: I have never worked with modin, but seems to be a tremendous tool to improve performance.